# Summary reports in FileMaker Pro 13

Tags: filemaker

When creating a report, is there a script that can be written that looks up the values of all the previous fields and if the current field is the same value, that value does not show on the list?

So the field will only show a value if its value is different that the previous values…

with one exception - at the beginning of a new slate number, it always prints the values for every field.

Comment: For more in-depth Filemaker issues, I'd suggest you join one of the FM community forums, for example http://fmforums.com

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to summarize the report by that field and show only the sub-summary part (i.e. remove the body part from the layout).